# How to enter in Visual block Mode in Vim by command

Tags: vim, command, key-bindings, mode

My system has Ctrl + V reserved for the use of the clipboard, so I cannot access to Vim's visual mode by using that combination of buttons.
Do you know what is the command such as `:VisualBlockModeEnable` or something similar to toggle this view?

Also I would like to change the binding in my `~/.vimrc`

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
:execute "normal! \<C-v>"
```

This will enter visual block mode.
To remap it use:

```
:nnoremap X <c-v>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the information from @Doktor, I do:

```
:command! Vb :execute "normal! \<C-v>"
```

Then I do `:Vb` if I want to enter it.

(I am using Alacritty to run NuShell, and I  have set C-v to paste text so I needed a workaround to enter Visual Block mode while keeping this setting.)